# async/await - not waiting before future() - Dart

Tags: asynchronous, dart, async-await, flutter

Based on Dart official page When using [Async/Wait](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures#async-await):

When the app sees the word `async` it execute the function normally synchronously, until it sees `await` or `return`

> Note that an async function starts executing right away
>   (synchronously). The function suspends execution and returns an
>   uncompleted future when it reaches the first occurrence of any of the
>   following:
>
> - The function’s first await expression (after the function gets the
>     uncompleted future from that expression).
> - Any return statement in the function.
> - The end of the function body.

and when it sees any of them it returns an uncompleted  `Future` and stops executing the `async` function until it execute all of the other functions, and when all of the other functions are executed, the app goes back to the `async` function and executes what's inside of it.

Here's a photo from the Dart official page explaining it in more details:
[image: Dart Image]

**But when I was testing that I tried to add a `print` statement before returning the future result as you can see in the below code, but the result wasn't as stated in the site, as it's saying that the app stops executing once it sees the word `await`but the statement: *"Async - Hi Called 1st"* was printed as you can see before the other functions were executed.**

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<void> print1stAsync() async {
  var test = await callAsync();
  print(test);
}

main() {
  print1stAsync();
  print2nd();
  print3rd();
  print4th();
}

print2nd() {
  print('Called 2nd');
}

print3rd() {
  print("Called 3rd");
}

print4th() {
  print('Called 4th');
}

Future<String> callAsync() {
  print("Async - Hi Called 1st");
    return Future(() => "Async - Called 1st ");
  }
```

Output:

```
Async - Hi Called 1st
Called 2nd
Called 3rd
Called 4th
Async - Called 1st
```

So why is this happening? have I miss understood something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The app doesn't stop executing, only the execution of the code after `await` is delayed until the returned `Future` completes.

You also need to await the call to the async function `print1stAsync()`, otherwise the execution of `main` continues after the call to `callAsync();` (after the call, not after the `Future` it returns completes)

```
main() async {
  await print1stAsync();
  print2nd();
  print3rd();
  print4th();
}
```

Add `async` to a function also means that this function returns a `Future`.
There is no way to go back from async to sync. Async is contagious.

`await callAsync();` means code below that line within the same function (like `print(test);` in your example) will be delayed.
It doesn't say anything about code in callAsync() or code that calls `print1stAsync();`

Comment: Is it okay to use `void` as return type instead of `Future<Null>` when not returning any value cause my IDE doesn't show any error and the code works same in both cases.

Comment: Yes it is ok. This signals fire-and-forget - the function communicates that it does not expected to be awaited. It's rather seldom used, but it's valid.

Comment: I understand that the execution is delayed until the completed `Future` is returned, but in the case of the code that I shared `print("Async - Hi Called 1st")` That one is called after `await` and before the completed `Future` is returned am I right? if that's the case why is `print("Async - Hi Called 1st")` executed then before the completed `Future` is returned?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. `print("Async - Hi Called 1st");` is executed immediately. There is no `await` before execution reaches that line. The `Future` returned from `print1stAsync` is completed when every `await`ed `Future` in `print1stAsync` is completed. If it is not awaited, code in `main` continues to execute async results in `printAsync()` are being waited for.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Ooh, so if I understood correctly `await callAsync();` doesn't mean that everything inside `callAsync();` will be delayed (because of the keyword `await`) BUT instead only what's called inside `future()` function will be delayed, am I right?

Comment: `await callAsync();` means code below that line within the same function (like `print(test);` in your example) will be delayed. It doesn't say anything about code in `callAsync()` or code that calls `print1stAsync`.

Comment: I understand it perfectly now, That was the magic sentence " await doesn't say anything about code in callAsync()". Thank you very much.